# Replace Regexp Matches In Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am new to regexp. I want to filter border values from a css code. eg= "border:1px solid grey"
or "border-top:1px solid grey". I have RegExp literal syntax as following

```js
var regexp= "/border[\w-]*\s*:\s*(\d+)px/g";
```

But I need RegExp class syntax

Can anyone suggest me RegExp class syntax?

Comment: what does `new RegExp("____"); ` supposed to mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of capturing the digits, you you capture what comes before and after in 2 capturing groups and only match the digits to be replaced.

The pattern `[\w-]*` could also possibly match `---`

Instead you could use an optional repeating group `(?:-\w+)*` to match a hyphen followed by 1 + characters.

```
(border(?:-\w+)*\s*:\s*)\d+(px)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yLVPQU/1)

In the replacement use the 2 capturing groups and note to double escape the backslashes in the RegExp constructor.

```js
let regex = new RegExp("(border(?:-\\w+)*\\s*:\\s*)\\d+(px)");
[
  "border:1px solid grey",
  "border-top:1px solid grey"
].forEach(s => console.log(s.replace(regex, "$199$2")));
```